# Did Gary Johnson not know who Harriet Tubman was?

Tags: united-states, politics, quotes

I've recently been seeing articles on Facebook and Google about 2016 US Presidential Nominee [Gary Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Johnson) being escorted into a room named after Abolitionist and US Civil War spy, [Harriet Tubman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_Tubman). He asked his aid "Who's Harriet Tubman?". This seems extremely similar to the recent news statements of "What is Aleppo" which he stated on live TV.

After doing some googling, I have found numerous sites that state he "reportedly" asked this question (usually with links to other sites that then state he reportedly asked this question). Is this a rumor that is just now circling around the internet or is this old news that is resurfacing?

Comment: [this](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/07/25/gary-johnson-the-third-party-candidate?reload?reload) is the original source for the claim. As there is no video evidence, there will likely be no confirmation of this story.

Comment: In light of aleppo, it sounds like satire to me.